# Using some kind of unit of measurement for scale?

Tags: scale, measurement

So I'm not very experienced in making scenes. So for my first attempt at doing so I want to make a scale model of my apartment. I'd like to make it last night and still possible, but I don't know how to turn gauge what the foot is in blender. If there's no built-in function for this, is there some way I can measure things to some kind of equivalent scale?

Answer (score 1):

In fact Blender could be switched to Metrics or Imperials using menu shown below...

[image]

...in my case, every single "rectangle" of the grey grid is one square metre. After switching to this You will be able to simply put the EXACT data in the "N" menu (right one) of your ViewPort where the Location or Size is (Location could be seen on the picture).

Hope it helps buddy, Jan.

Comment: another neat feature is the blender will also convert for you once you set a unit.  Like if you set to Metric, you can type "1 in" in a numeric field and it will change to 2.54 cm.